# LocationManager gives NETWORK_PROVIDER disabled

Tags: android, location

I need to retrieve user's location by 3G or WIFI.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                manageLocation(location);
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

The problem is that the only callback that is called is `onProviderDisabled` giving `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` as parameter.

I've got that permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

How can I enable that type of location in my application?

Comment: I can confirm @kkarakk : Android pie returns LocationManager.NetworkProvider as disabled even when location toggle is enabled.
And I was not able to enable it. Btw, even Google map doesn't show any position without GPS enabled. As far as I remember, in the past I've seen area where I am (based on network ?) without GPS.
But maybe I'm wrong, I've no old device anymore to verify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user needs to go into the device's Settings app and enable location providers. You cannot enable that yourself directly.

Comment: so user needs to have gps enabled

Comment: @JackTurky: The user needs to have locations enabled, not necessarily GPS specifically. Whether or not the device supports enabling/disabling individual location data sources is up to the OS version and, to a lesser extent, the device manufacturer.

Comment: @CommonsWare But i can see my location being enabled in my app in settings. Why do I still get it disabled?

Comment: @user1017674: Sorry, but I do not know what you mean. You might want to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve].

Comment: Android pie returns LocationManager.NetworkProvider as disabled even when location toggle is enabled. ran into this issue today

Comment: I can confirm @kkarakk : Android pie returns LocationManager.NetworkProvider as disabled even when location toggle is enabled.

Comment: Hello, I am also facing this LoactionManager.NetworkProvider disabled issue in Android PIE. Is there anyone who got its solution. Plz help

Comment: Facing the same. The not entirely convincing, https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all suggests that they've taken a step towards making location based on wifi completely impossible.

Comment: I am getting network provider disabled on marshmallow even if my location is unabled