# Current Latitude And Longitude Not Shown

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app in Android Studio where the user can save their current latitude and longitude in Firebase. I am using this code:

```
public class SaveLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

TextView saveLatitude, saveLongitude;
Button saveLocationBtn;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
LocationManager locationManager;
Double latitude,longitude;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_save_location);

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("User");

    saveLatitude = findViewById(R.id.saveLatitude);
    saveLongitude = findViewById(R.id.saveLongitude);
    saveLocationBtn = findViewById(R.id.saveLocationBtn);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);

    }

    saveLocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getLocation();
        }
    });

}

public void getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 5, SaveLocationActivity.this);
    }
    catch (SecurityException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    latitude=location.getLatitude();
    String latStr=latitude.toString();

    longitude=location.getLongitude();
    String longStr=longitude.toString();

    saveLatitude.setText(latStr);
    saveLongitude.setText(longStr);

    databaseReference.push().setValue("Latitude : "+latStr);
    databaseReference.push().setValue("Longitude : "+longStr);

    Toast.makeText(SaveLocationActivity.this, "Location Saved !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent i=new Intent(SaveLocationActivity.this,DisplayProfile.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
    SaveLocationActivity.this.finish();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(SaveLocationActivity.this, "Please Enable GPS and Internet !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

Now whenever I am running this app in my phone it shows the Toast message "Please Enable GPS and Internet !!!" inspite of the fact that I have my Location on in phone and also have a working internet connection. I am actually using my home wifi for internet connection. If anyone find any mistake in my code please let me know also please suggest me a possible solution.

Comment: You are using `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`. Maybe it requires a SIM card(?) There are [methods to check](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationProvider.html?hl=en#requiresCell()) if cellular network or internet are needed. Also the [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440189/locationmanager-gives-network-provider-disabled) suggest that "Android Pie (i.e. Android 9) returns LocationManager.NetworkProvider as disabled even when location toggle is enabled", but I don't know anything more about that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this permissions to your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: I have only added fine location. Do I need to add coarse location as well?

Comment: Maybe just to be safe. If not you can try to use fused location, this will try to get location from all possible places that it can. If not you can also try to get GPS_PROVIDER location instead of network

Comment: Yes now its working and thanks a lot for the help. I just have another question that I don't  want to update the values of latitude and longitude. I just want to store it for once. So is there any way that I could do that. Can I somehow change the value of time in locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 5, SaveLocationActivity.this);
method so that it doesn't update the values every second?

Comment: If you only want it once can use locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) which will return the last value the phone received.

Comment: So you mean instead of these two methods : locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 5, SaveLocationActivity.this);
    
I use locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) right?

Comment: The `getLastKnownLocation()` might not return any location or it might return a location that's no longer up-to-date. It's not such a great option. And it might not work at all with the current problem that you are having, so it probably needs to be solved anyway.

Comment: What markus said is complete right. The last known location may be outdated, or it might just be null. Your best solution my be using a Location Listener